# Как разделить HTML-файл на блоки, находящиеся в разных файлах?

Tags: html, cms, include

У меня есть HTML страницы, и в каждой странице *header*, *sidebar* и *footer* повторяются, но *content* - разный.

Как разделить эту страницу на отдельные? Например, видел у некоторых CMS такие строки: `include header.php`, `include footer.php`.

Как сделать так, чтобы в каждой странице HTML-код не повторялся, а просто вставлялся (`include`)?

Comment: Cпасибо за корректировку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно создать, следуя вашему примеру, файлы: `header.php`, `sidebar.php`   и `footer.php` с содержимым которые вы хотите видеть на вашей странице. Напрмер так:

**head.php**

```
<?php
        //Здесь подключаем стили и скрипты
        echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https:\/\/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com\/bootstrap\/3.3.5\/css\/bootstrap.min.css\">";

  ?>
```

**header.php**

```
 <?php
    //Мой header.php
    echo "Текст, содержащийся в хедере";

 ?>
```

**footer.php**

```
 <?php
    //Мой footer.php
    echo "Текст, содержащийся в футере";

 ?>
```

**Основной файл:**

```
<html>
   <head>
       <?php include 'head.php';?>
   </head>
   <body>

    <div class="header">
    <?php include 'header.php';?>
    </div>

     <h1>Привет!</h1>
     <p>Как у тебя дела? </p>

      <div class="footer">
      <?php include 'footer.php';?>
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: а в header-e же делается инклуд php,css,js и т.д, так почему хидер помещен в `<body>`? Это не повлияет на работу инклуденных файлов?

Comment: @Ersultan, конечно повлияет. Если то что вы инклудите должно быть в head  то просто разместите `<?php include 'head.php';?>` в нужном месте -   внутри html элемента <head></head>. И думаю вы спутали элемент HTML <head> c абстрактым понятием header. Пример поправил.

Comment: а есть ли вероятность того что сайт будет работать хоть чуточку быстрее используя этот метод,чем загружать каждый раз в каждой странице header/footer?

Comment: @Ersultan, боюсь на скорость полета это не влияет.  Скорее наоборот. К примеру у Вас на одной странице используется одна библиотека кот занимает 1мб. И если вы испольщуете такой подход, на другой странице где эта библиотека будет подключена, но не будет использована, то Вы лишь увеличите время загрузки этой страницы на загрузку ненужной библиотеки. Инклуды это лишь способ сократить поторяющийся код и облегчить дальнейшее редактирование сайта.

Answer (score 1):

Дополнение к правильному ответу, эти файлы не обязаны быть .php, include -это простое включение текста одного файла в другой в определенном месте. Получается, что лучше их назвать по другому, так как это не исполняемые файлы, чтобы не путать в проекте.

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php